Snap Store doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04
This morning I update/upgrade packages in my Ubuntu 22.04.5 and discovered that snaps don't refresh. Snap returns this error message.
cannot refresh: cannot query the store for updates:   
got unexpected HTTP status code 503 via POST to https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh".   

The Ubuntu Software app doesn't connect either. I have ping to api.snapcraft.io and snap was updated yesterday without errors. I didn't find any information for this case in the internet.

Your issue maybe just temporary issues, relating to Canonical doing some network/server migrations...   ie. in a hour or so, or at worst a day or so, the issue may resolved  (could also be the snapcraft/snap store isn't involved with migrations, I'm just aware some Canonical/Ubuntu servers are impacted)

@guiverc This question is tricky because even though it might easily be a temporary issue I was unable to find another question with the same error message at Ask Ubuntu. Maybe it should be answered or maybe it's not reproducible because it's a temporary issue.

@karel For now anyway; it's a legit question... but I cannot confirm that server migrations are the cause; I'm only aware that they are occurring, (and its why some builds are not currently not taking place..) and thus left my comment...

Looks like the service is back up now: https://status.snapcraft.io/

The snap servers are down, and have been for a while:

Active Incident Outage of various Snap functionalities This incident
has been open for 2 hours 37 mins 10 secs. Incident Start Time Nov 07,
2024 03:00:00 PM AEST

It's 5:40 pm, AEST right now
You can follow for updates on Snap's service outage here:
https://status.snapcraft.io/
